# How to upload all formats of docs, Videos and see the preview of the doc using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, video-upload

Uploaded files unable to see in the carousel, Im able to see video and image files, please suggest me to see all formats of the docs as well.

```
  mydata = []
  onSelectFile(event) {
    const files = event.target.files;
    if (files) {
      for (const file of files) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e: any) => {
          if (file.type.indexOf("image") > -1) {
            this.mydata.push({
              url:e.target.result,
              type: 'img'
            });
          } else if (file.type.indexOf("video") > -1) {
            this.mydata.push({
              url:e.target.result,
              type: 'video'
            });
          }else if (file.type.indexOf("ppt") > -1) {
               this.mydata.push({
              url:e.target.result,
             type: 'ppt'
        });
      }

        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
    }
  }
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-image-video-preview-final-snnv2p?file=app%2Fapp.component.html,app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: In your stackblitz example you mention PDF, in your code you mention PPT.

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML template (on stackblitz) you are referencing an  for the PDF document. According to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object) from Mozilla you have to add the type of document as well. So in this case (pdf) you have to specify:

```
<object *ngIf="list.type == 'pdf'" [data]="list.url" type="application/pdf"></object>
```

Then the PDF gets rendered. For other types of documents you have to specify the correct type (see docs).